# syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">= 75 ")

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash
   CURRENT=$(df -h / | grep / | awk '{ print $4}')
   THRESHOLD=75

   if (( "$CURRENT" >= "$THRESHOLD" )); then
       mail -s "CENTOS-6 localhost 10.10.1.238 Disk Space Alert" sss@abc.net << EOF
   Your root partition remaining free space is critically low. Used: $CURRENT%
   EOF
   fi
```

I got the following error when i run the script, syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">= 75 ")

Comment: your CURRENT value isn't numeric, so you can't use >= operator on it (it contains non-numeric suffix to be human-readable, as requested by -h operator). Or maybe in your case it's percents in fourth column - it will have '%' sign then (it's fifth column in my case)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `CURRENT` will contain a percent sign, so it won't be a valid operand for the comparison operation.

You can remove the last character like this :

```
CURRENT=${CURRENT%?};
```

Also make sure that `df -h / | grep / | awk '{ print $4}'` is correctly returning the usage ratio, on most systems you have to use `print $5`.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:

```
CURRENT=$(df -h |awk '{print $4}' |sort -n |tail -n1 |sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=90

if [ $THRESHOLD -gt $CURRENT ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- you don't need `grep` at all, `awk` is quite capable of doing it's own regex stuff.
- if you search for `/` in the `df` output, you'll probably get *most* lines as most mounts have a `/` somewhere in them. If you just want the root mountpoint, you can use `<space>/$`.
- Check that `4` is the correct field number, on my box it's `5`.
- In any case, that field is of the form `55%` which will not be considered numeric. You can use `gsub` to get rid of it.

With that in mind, the following snippet can be used to get the percentage:

```
df -h | awk '$0 ~ / \/$/ { gsub("%","",$5); print $5 }'
```

---

And, just as an aside, I'm not *that* big a fan of here-docs in shell scripts since it either (1) screws up my nicely indented files; or (2) makes me burn half an hour while I try to remember the various syntax options which will allow indented `EOF` strings :-)

I prefer something like:

```
(
    echo Your root partition remaining free space is critically low: Used: ${CURRENT}%
) | mail -s "CENTOS-6 localhost 10.10.1.238 Disk Space Alert" sss@abc.net
```

*Especially* since that means I can put arbitrarily complex commands in the sub-shell to generate whatever info I want in the mail message (rather than just simple text substitutions).

---

So, bottom line, I'd be looking at something more like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Config section.

LIMIT=75

# Code section.

CURR=$(df -h | awk '$0 ~ / \/$/ { gsub("%","",$5); print $5 }')
if [[ ${CURR} -ge ${LIMIT} ]] ; then
    (
        echo "Your root partition remaining free space is critically low: Used: ${CURR}%"
    ) | mail -s "CENTOS-6 localhost 10.10.1.238 Disk Space Alert" sss@abc.net
fi
```